# What is the difference between iPhone Developer Standard Program (99 USD) and Enterprise Program (299 USD)?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipod-touch

Can someone point out what is the difference?

And what for do we actually pay so much money, when supporting the iPhone with our hard work?

Is it right that I have to have the Enterprise Membership (299 USD), when I want to sell Apps for money? Or can I also sell Apps when I "only" have the cheaper Standard Membership (99 USD)?

Is there a fee every time I want to upload a new app to the App Store? Where is the hook in the Standard Membership?

Comment: I wish this was clearly documented at http://developer.apple.com/iphone/program/apply.html . Oh, wait...

Comment: When does $99/year constitute "so much money"?  If you're developing Windows software, you're likely paying more for development tools, while for Apple and iPhone good-quality development tools are free.

Comment: @David Thornley: Well, check out Code::Blocks ;) Otherwise, agreed

Answer (score 9):

The Enterprise Membership is only for enterprises - no app store distribution, but you can distribute your programs within your enterprise (ad-hoc). With the Standard one, you can put your apps on the app store but can only give out 100 copies of your program using ad-hoc.
There is no fee for submitting apps to the App Store once you have a Standard membership.

Comment: so with the Enterprise Membership I could estably my very own version of an "App Store" for my apps, so that people from my website buy instantly my apps and download them from my page directly??

Comment: This may be possible but it is probably a violation of Apple's terms.

Comment: One critical step here is that your company has to prove to Apple it has 500 or more full time employees.  Apple use your business Dun & Bradstreet number to confirm this.  If you need to update the information in your D & B number (e.g. if it is out of date like mine was), you will find it takes at least 3 weeks.  I am still waiting after 3 weeks!

This 500 employee limit is arbitrary and infuriating.  What do you do if you have between 100 and 500 employees?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to distribute both to your organization via adhoc and the public via App Store, you need to register two separate accounts.  This was confirmed in an email from Apple Dev Support.

Comment: I think that is the case, see this page which seems to imply they are completely separate accounts: 
http://developer.apple.com/iphone/program/apply.html

Answer (score 2):

From [Apple](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/program/apply.html):

The standard plan does NOT allow distribution to iPhones (except a few development phones) outside of the app store.

The enterprise plan does NOT allow distribution to iPhone via the app store, but does permit developers to deploy their own programs within their own organization without designating those phones as 'development' phones.

-Adam

Answer (score 0):

"The standard plan does NOT allow distribution to iPhones (except a few development phones)"

how many phones??

Comment: Maximum of 100 devices (iPhones and iPod Touches).